# Speech to text with react-native-community/voice is not giving proper result in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-voice

I am using speech to text using react-native-community/voice. For android, it is working fine but for iOS, it is not giving proper results. I tried using hooks also but getting the same result.

I used timer of 5 seconds to handle destroy voice method(It was also not working on my iOS project).

I'm using

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8
```

Can someone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code: -

```
     state = {
     recognized: '',
     pitch: '',
     error: '',
     end: '',
     started: '',
     results: [],
     partialResults: [],
     dataSource: [],
     isNet:false,
     isLoading : false,
    };
 
    constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechRecognized = this.onSpeechRecognized;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = this.onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = this.onSpeechPartialResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = this.onSpeechVolumeChanged;
    }
 
    componentWillUnmount() {
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    }
 
    onSpeechStart = (e: any) => {
     this.setState({
     started: '',
    });
    };
 
    onSpeechRecognized = (e: SpeechRecognizedEvent) => {
    this.setState({
     recognized: '',
    });
    };
 
    onSpeechEnd = (e: any) => {
     this.setState({
      end: '',
    });
    };
 
    onSpeechError = (e: SpeechErrorEvent) => {
    this.setState({
     error: JSON.stringify(e.error),
    });
    };
 
     onSpeechResults = (e: SpeechResultsEvent) => {
     this.setState({
      results: e.value,
     });
     // My Own Method this.getSearchResult(e.value[0])
     };
 
     onSpeechPartialResults = (e: SpeechResultsEvent) => {
      this.setState({
      partialResults: e.value,
      });
     };
 
     onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e: any) => {
     this.setState({
      pitch: e.value,
      });
    };
 
     _startRecognizing = async () => {
      this.setState({
      recognized: '',
      pitch: '',
      error: '',
      started: '',
      results: [],
      partialResults: [],
      end: 'Listning ...',
    });
 
   try {
     Platform.OS === 'ios'
     {
       setTimeout(() => {
         this._destroyRecognizer()
       }, 5000)
     }
     await Voice.start('en-US');
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
 };
 
 _stopRecognizing = async () => {
   try {
     await Voice.stop();
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
 };
 
 _cancelRecognizing = async () => {
   try {
     await Voice.cancel();
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
 };
 
 _destroyRecognizer = async () => {
   try {
     await Voice.destroy();
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e);
   }
   this.setState({
     recognized: '',
     pitch: '',
     error: '',
     started: '',
     results: [],
     partialResults: [],
     end: '',
   });
 };
```

Any help will appreciate

Comment: "It's not working" is *not* a good description of a problem.

Comment: @Ankit Singh were you able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and I just workaround it with this

```
// for ios
onSpeechEnd(e) {
    this.setState({
      end: true
    });
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      // use this.state.results here
    }
  }
// for android
  onSpeechResults(e) {
    this.setState({
      results: e.value
    });
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      use this.state.results here
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, in my case i am getting undefined the value of  ```e```  on onSpeechEnd method

Comment: yes that is ob, you need to access to your this.state.results there.

Comment: My question is about translation. Voice to text it is not giving proper result for example i spoke "aloevera" then it returns "Hello vera", "Elevator" etc.

Comment: did you guys got the solution
@AnkitSingh